# program calculates how many printable characters are in an array of characters that entered by user

Tags: c

I am getting the wrong results. I am not sure what is causing the problem. The task is to calculate the number of printable characters inside an array of characters given by user-input. The output `r` always equals 0 (zero) no matter what input is given.

```
printf("Geben sie bitte einen Zeichenkette ein \n");
fgets(s1, sizeof(s1), stdin);   
int r=0;
int size = sizeof(s1)/sizeof(s1[0]);    
for (i=0;i<=size;i++){
    char a=s1[i];
    int h = (int)a;
    if (isprint(h)==1){
        r=r++;
    }
}
printf("%d\n",r);
return 0;
```

Comment: `r=r++;` Put `r++;` instead. But that's probably not the only problem. Without a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's hard to say.

Comment: use `strlen(s1)` to get the number of read bytes, not `sizeof(s1)/sizeof(s1[0])`. This is the size of the buffer, which is probably uninitialized

Comment: `isprint()` returns a non-zero value; not necessarily 1, when the character is printable.  Use just `if (isprint(h))`.  Also, you should probably cast to unsigned char in case plain `char` is a signed type: `if (isprint((unsigned char)h))`.

Comment: Make sure to not read beyond the size of the array. Array indexes range from `0` to `size - 1` !  `size` is *not* a valid array index.

Answer (score 1):

#### Your code:

```
if (isprint(h)==1){  // Why compare against 1?  What does that do?
        r=r++;       // Do you know how ++ works?? Read about it.
    }
```

---

#### Fixed Version

```
if (isprint(h)) {
    r++;
}
```

Comment: Cast to unsigned char?

Answer (score 0):

The main problems are: Wrong calculation of input length (use strlen instead of the buffer size), wrong incrementing of variable `r` ( `r =`r++`invokes undefined behaviour), and invalid assumptions on the return value of`isprint()` (which does not need to be 1 on true).

Now, if we put it all together, the fixed version is:

```
char s1[BUFSIZE];
int i, r = 0;

printf("Geben sie bitte einen Zeichenkette ein\n");
fgets(s1, sizeof(s1), stdin);

for (i = 0; i < strlen(s1); i++) {
    if (isprint(s1[i]))
        r++;
}

printf("%d\n", r);
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
r=r++;
```

invokes undefined behavior.

This loop

```
int size = sizeof(s1)/sizeof(s1[0]);    

for (i=0;i<=size;i++){
```

also can invoke undefined behavior when the size of the stored string is less than the size of the character array. And moreover there is an attempt to access the memory outside the character array.

In this declaration

```
int h = (int)a;
```

you have to cast the character a to the type unsigned char.

```
int h = ( unsigned char )a;
```

What you need us the following

```
    printf("Geben sie bitte einen Zeichenkette ein \n");
    fgets(s1, sizeof(s1), stdin);   
    int r=0;

    for ( i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        r += isprint( ( unsigned char ) s[i] ) != 0;
    }

    printf("%d\n",r);
    return 0;
}
```